# How I can use c++11's regex for matching some generic bytes?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need to do this:

```
const regex setData("^(setDataArray:)[\\x00-\\xFF]{8,8}$");
```

In other word I need to identify a string followed by some generic bytes (it is an internet protocol), but it give me an error at runtime, during compilation of the object.
I think the reason is that I can't just use an 8-bit char. There's a way to fix it?

**EDIT:** As suggested I'm attaching a simple program that explain the problem:

```
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

const regex setData("^(setDataArray:)[\\x00-\\xFF]{8,8}$");

int main()
{
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This program crashes on 3rd line when compiled with visual studio 2013 on Windows 8.1

Comment: ...you mean your looking for "hex" notation? So your looking for setDataArray:x25 ect? or your looking for an any character? (I've never used regex for non-plane-text processing, so I don't know if this is even possible...)

Comment: Here is an [ECMAScript regex cheat sheet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/) and should your string be `const regex setData("^(setDataArray:)[\\x00-\\xFF]{8}$");` instead (change `{8,8}` to `{8}`?  Your pattern is searching for 8 hex ASCII characters.  Are these ASCII strings or UNICODE strings?

Comment: The fixed string I need to match (setDataArray) is plain ASCII, but the other part is not actually a string. Is just a group of bytes (a mask).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams To clarify: I'm not trying to match "setDataArray:x25" and so on, nor I'm looking for "any characters". I need to match "setDataArray:" followed by eight generic bytes (and this include character, control codes etc. from null character to \xFF)

Comment: The zero byte in your range `\\x00` will never be matched as part of the string, it will be matched as end of the string `$`. You will have to somehow pass a size of your buffer to the matching algorithm, which regular expressions cannot do, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @SevaTitov: it can work using an iterator.  See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578fd145d0c7d49b for an example.

Comment: Sorry, wrong example.  Try this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac3cc1a8b2ec9448

Comment: Hey do you need to escape the colon (:)?

Comment: @Edward, your source string does not contain character 0. Try inserting \x00 into the string, you will see that parsing stops on it. Zero character is only matched as end of string `$`.

Comment: @SevaTitov: My first example didn't contain embedded \0 but second one does, and the parsing continues past that to the end of the `std::string`.

Comment: Ok, these are good starting point, thanks! But my program still crash if I try to match characters from \x80 to \xFF (compiled with MSVC++12).

Comment: @chaplin89: could you post a little more context?  What would be ideal is a short complete example including input, expected output, actual output and tool/operating system.

Comment: @Edward the program crashes when try to inizialize the object of the 1st post, which is global (so the program crash before entering main or any other function!). The call stack start with: Server.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'setData''() Line 27    C++
But if I change \xFF to \x7F the code work! So AFAIK regex have some problem with 8-bit char, which is comprensible because an 8-bit char is not an ASCII char, the question is: how can I fix?
I'm running MSVC++12 on Windows 8.1!

Comment: @chaplin89 You haven't shown the lines of code in which you're actually using the regex, so it's hard to say.  If you're using a `std::string` as the container you're searching, be aware that it's defined as `std::basic_string<char>` rather than `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` so that could be a factor.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm not explaing well (sorry but I'm not english):
the program crash here->

      const regex setData("^(setDataArray:)[\\x00-\\xFF]{8,8}$");

and this object is global, so actually is outside main function.
The line that use the regex is this:

     else if (regex_search(msg.c_str(), setData)) 

but the program not even reach this line (nor enter main!). If I change \xFF with \x7F the program work!

Comment: Can you remove everything except the `const regex setData(...)` line and a simple `main`, recompile as a single standalone program and still get it to crash?  If so, post that.

Comment: Ok, so this program: http://pastebin.com/BhRYT18a actually crash in visual studio 2013

Comment: @chaplin89 Wow!  Can you edit your question and paste in that code?  That's a much better illustration of the problem.

Comment: So it sounds like the regex constructor is crashing.  I took your example and put the constructor into the main() and found an exception being thrown by regex (std::regex_error) and the text says invalid escape character.

Comment: Looks to me like using range `[\\x00-\\xFF]` is the problem.  can you use hex constants in a range like that?

Comment: Supposedly not..it works only in the range [\\x00-\\x7F] (1st bit==0).

Comment: I suggest you use the regex to search for the text `setDataArray:` and if found double check to see what comes after.

Comment: Yeah, I know that there are plenty simpler ways to do this (in fact, I can just check the lenght of the string) but I was wondering if I can do this with the regex because the string I want to check is more complex than it seems here, and using regex gave me the possibility to use the facilities of cmatch/smatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
const regex setData(R"(^(setDataArray:)[\x00-\xFF]{8,8}$)", 
      std::regex_constants::basic);
```

I changed the syntax to use a Raw string constant, (the `R"( ... )"` syntax) to avoid having to escape slash characters and making it easier to read, but that's just to make it pretty.

The consequential change was the addition of the `std::regex_constants::basic` causes the regex to use the basic Posix grammar instead of the default ECMAScript grammar.  In this case there should *not* be a problem using the ECMAScript version but I suspect there may be a problem in Microsoft's implementation.

There is a subtle difference between the standard ECMAScript grammar and that of the slightly modified version used in C++11.  In particular the character range `[B-E]` form is *not* part of the original ECMAScript grammar, but *is* specified as part of the ECMAScript grammar as used in C++11.

You can read more about the various grammars and what they provide at 
[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/constants)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and the working example!